# Svn hook on commit makes lock

Tags: svn

My post-commit hook looks like this:

```
pushd C:\Websites\Project

svn update
```

I am updating my server copy of repository.

When I commit client stopped on sending content and locked or I dont know. Its is waiting for something. So when I cancel and try to update manually on server, I see:

```
Working copy "." lockedsvn
```

And only after manual cleanup and update again, I get updated revision, that was really commited.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

- Is `svn update` stopping to ask for a password? Commit hooks are non-interactive, so if svn update asks for a password, then there'll be no way to enter it. Try doing `svn update --username xxxx --password xxxx --non-interactive` (replacing as appropriate).
- Try redircting the output of `svn update` to file so you can see what it's doing (e.g., `svn update > my.debug.file.log`), then if that doesn't shed any light, report back here to see if anyone can give more information.

Note also that the SVN FAQ has a section on this here: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#website-auto-update ... pay attention to the discussion in there regarding directory permissions on the target.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you `svn update` is actually taking place and the post-commit hook is just waiting for it to complete (you don't say how long you wait for it to complete).

This could be just because there's lots of content being updated, alternatively it could be that your update is blocked because there's a merge conflict between the working copy in `C:\Websites\Project` and the update which needs resolved.

Comment: No merge or anything. Its simple commit with one test line changed in one file. You are saying its should work? Or its working for you.

Comment: Saying it should work - don't have a Windows SVN environment to try it on.